# A blank blue screen appear when I finish installation Kali Linux 2020.1, in VMware workstation pro, and login

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation

I have just installed Kali Linux 2020.1 in vmware workstation. After installation finished, I was asked to login, so I did and a blue screen appeared. It has no icon, no terminal or other things. The cursor is working, means screen is not stuck, and on right click it is showing a three element menu?

What could be the possible solution?

Comment: i mean , what is the solution so that i can see all desktop icons ..terminal etc

Comment: this may help you ... https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/5361#5361